# XML dont get rendered for special charcters in the browser from SharePoint site

Tags: xslt, xml

This may not be related to SharePoint but since I got this error from my SharePoint site, I am posting in this forum. So Please do not put it on hold.

I have a properly generated XML file in one of my Sharepoint library. If I download and open the file. It get opens properly but when I click on it, it opens in browser and it breaks at line having special character like ***å*** ***Æ*** ***Ã***. It says **Cannot view XML input using XSL style sheet**

What is the reson of this? Once I replace these character with their unicode decimal value, I am able to open the XML in browser without any error.

Please let me know the cause why this is breaking in browser?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SharePoint. This is a Browser issue.

Comment: yeah I know..check my first line...its not browser its related to rendering of HTML

Comment: You say it breaks when opening in browser, so this is a browser issue.

Comment: browser like any browser.. its basically an xml issue which breaks on rendering in an html browser page.